# Qstring to LPCWSTR

Tags: qt

```
LPCWSTR path;

void WinApiLibrary::StartProcess(QString name)
{
    path = name.utf16();
    CreateProcess(path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

> C:\kursovaya\smc\winapilibrary.cpp:21: error: invalid conversion from
>   'const ushort* {aka const short unsigned int*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const
>   wchar_t*}' [-fpermissive]
>        path = name.utf16();

This code worked in the Qt 4.8, but now i have Qt 5.2 and this code isn't working. What's wrong with this guy?

Comment: Make additional casting to LPCWSTR.

Comment: Slight nitpick: if you're using Qt, why do you even bother with `CreateProcess`? Just use `QProcess`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QString::utf16()` returns `const ushort*`, which is different from `const wchar_t*`, so you have the compile error.

You are probably compiling with `/Zc:wchar_t`. If you change it to `/Zc:wchar_t-` it should work, as `wchar_t` type becomes typedef to 16-bit integer in this case.

In Visual Studio: Project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Treat WChar_t As Built in Type->No.

Or just add `reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But where can i find it in QtCreator?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the issue. You are building with MinGW, that's why the error. Also, `QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS += /Zc:wchar_t-` won't help, as this is Microsoft Visual C++ compiler switch, g++ won't understand it. I think `reinterpret_cast` would be the only solution in this case.

Comment: I think we should add a toWCharArray to QString in the future. I saw many people doing these nasty reinterpret casts. :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp There's already `toStdWString()`, but it returns the string in different encodings on Windows and other platforms.

Comment: @Paul: that expands to std::wstring rather than wchar_t, so I think I will ask the qt developers if it makes sense to add a feature like this to 5.3.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue (I'm using Qt 5.3), this is how I fixed it:

```
QString strVariable1;
LPCWSTR strVariable2 = (const wchar_t*) strVariable1.utf16();
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `Qt 5.2` and I had the same issue. This is how I fixed it:

```
QString sPath = "C:\\Program File\\MyProg";
wchar_t wcPath[1024];
int iLen = sPath.toWCharArray(wcPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Qt global namespace, there is the macro [qUtf16Printable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qUtf16Printable). However as the documentation states, this produces a temporary so take care to use it properly. Note this was introduced in Qt5.7.