# CopyFileExW fails with 0 for an existing file

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, file-copying

**Context:**

I have an application that searches files in a directory using `QDirIterator`, filters and copies specific files.

**Problem:**

Using the results from [QDirIterator::next()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html#next), I ensure the file exists (as a unnecessary safe measure) using [QFile::exists(QString)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#exists) which is valid.

However, when attempting to copy the file using [CopyFileExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw), it [returns 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw#return-value) meaning the file copy failed. I have absolutely no idea why.

**File location:**

```
C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658/zoom_0.mp4
```

---

**Sanity Tests**

I added some sanity tests to check the file content through the conversion from `QString` -> `LPCWSTR` as `FileCopyExW` requires `LPCWSTR` and it is suggested to convert `QString -> LPCWSTR` [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65546-Can-t-convert-QString-to-LPCWSTR?p=289096#post289096).

*Regarding the conversion, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26366143/4628115) too but it yields the same result. It is also suggested as bad practice to user c-style casts*

Sanity tests (in application code below) all pass, but `FileCopyExW` always fails with:

> "Error 0x80070002: The system cannot find the file specified."

Code inside application:

```
QString m_src = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658/zoom_0.mp4");
QString m_dst = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658/zoom_0.mp42");
     
// Hard coded test location attempting to match variables' content below
//    QString srcLocation = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 10.41.17 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 96047275811/zoom_0.mp4");
//    QString dstLocation = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 10.41.17 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 96047275811/zoom_0.mp44");

//    std::wstring srcWString1 = srcLocation.toStdWString();
//    std::wstring dstWString1 = dstLocation.toStdWString();

//    const wchar_t* localC_src1 = srcLocation.toStdWString().c_str();
//    const wchar_t* localC_dst1 = dstLocation.toStdWString().c_str();
//
//    std::wstring srcWString = m_src.toStdWString();
//    std::wstring dstWString = m_dst.toStdWString();


// Used inside copy function
    const wchar_t* localC_src = m_src.toStdWString().c_str();
    const wchar_t* localC_dst = m_dst.toStdWString().c_str();
    
    // Sanity tests
     if (m_src.contains("96047275811/zoom_0.mp4")) {
          if (srcLocation != m_src) {
               qDebug() << "Warning";            // Never gets hit
          }
          if (srcWString != srcWString1) {
               qDebug() << "Warning";            // Never gets hit
          }
          if (*localC_src != *localC_src1) {
               qDebug() << "Warning";            // Never gets hit
          }

          if (!QFile::exists(srcLocation)) {
               qDebug() << "Warning";             // Never gets hit
          }
     }
     auto rc = CopyFileExW(localC_src, localC_dst, &FileManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {
          printWarning(TAG, QString("File Copy Error: %1").arg(getLastErrorMsg()));
          // copy failed
          return FileResult::IOError;               // This file always hits
     }

     // copy success
     return FileResult::Success;
```

However, hard coding the file location in a custom test application does indeed work correctly.

**Testing Application:**

*Result is successful*

```
static QString toString(HRESULT hr)
{
     _com_error err{hr};
     const TCHAR* lastError = err.ErrorMessage();
     return QStringLiteral("Error 0x%1: %2").arg((quint32)hr, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0'))
            .arg(lastError);
}

static QString getLastErrorMsg()
{
     QString s = toString(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()));
     return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

     QString m_src = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658/zoom_0.mp4");
     QString m_dst = QString("C:/Users/CybeX/Documents/BLMS/Repo/BLMS-Work-Dev/Meeting 2 - Requirements Document Discussion & Dev/2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658/zoom_0.mp42");

     auto rc = CopyFileExW(m_src.toStdWString().c_str(), m_dst.toStdWString().c_str(),
                           NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {
          QString s = getLastErrorMsg();
          // copy failed
          qDebug() << "Failed";
     }
     else {
          qDebug() << "Copied";                    // Always gets hit
     }

     // copy success
     return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Attach a native debugger (e.g. windbg or cdb) to the process with a breakpoint set on `CopyFileExW`. When the breakpoint hits, examine the arguments that get passed, particularly the source and destination path. In x64, they're passed in registers rcx and rdx -- e.g. `du @rcx` prints the source path.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks for the comment, see my answer. It is not related to the conversion at all...surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer for the record - hopefully someone else will benefit from it.

The result of [GetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returned 3, which according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) means a section in the path cannot be found, not the file, but the path, i.e. a directory. This got me thinking to debug the folder path.

After copying the same file to various directories along the path, and each was detected, I narrowed down the problematic path component `2020-05-19 11.22.30 Someone Person's Zoom Meeting 98661954658` it down to the folder name containing the single-quotation.

*This was a happy mistake where I was working in the destination folder* However, attempting to make a copy of the directory (to remove the single quote), Windows complained the path was too long (this was a folder that was already copied, containing the problematic file).

**Summary**

Basically, the source file was fine, the destination directory was created (programatically), but the copying the file to the destination resulted in a path too long for Windows, causing the 'system cannot find path' error (trickery!)

**TL;DR:**

Destination path was too long, resulting in a possibly misleading error code.

Comment: I'm missing something in your explanation. A single quote character (`'`) is a valid filename character in FAT32 and NTFS, and none of the paths you showed in your examples are anywhere near the classic `MAX_PATH` (260) limit.

Comment: BTW, a Windows 10 system can enable long paths at the system level for applications that declare that they're long path aware in their manifest. Also, a vebatim path that's prefixed with `"\\\\?\\"` has the native limit of about 32,760 characters, but should first be normalized via `GetFullPathNameW` before prepending the prefix in order to ensure the filename is proper (no trailing spaces and dots; no reserved DOS device names) and to ensure that the path is fully qualified, with all "." and ".." components resolved, and only using backslash as the path separator.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @ZhuSong I need to make some edits so that it is more clear, but I will certainly be doing so :)